# Whats a best practice for implementing a hierarchical relation in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'd like to model users that belong to groups, and groups that belong to groups, so I'm thinking along the lines of (forgive the newb syntax):

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :group_id, :name
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :name
  has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
end
```

Would the above be a preferred way to implement this?  Is there a simple way of deleting a 'parent' group and have it delete it's children?

At the time of the writing, I'm learning with rails 3.2.x ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing here - but would users be able to be in multiple groups and groups would only be in one (a parent group)?

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :name
  has_many :groups, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :group_users, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :users, :through => :group_users
  belongs_to :parent_group, :class_name => :group
end

class GroupUsers < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :name
  has_many :group_users, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :groups, :through => :group_users
end
```

Comment: So, if I follow ... a group can have multiple users, and each group can only have one parent, ***and in turn a parent group itself can be child of another parent***.  If yes, than it's perfect.

Comment: Yes - that's how this is set up.  Users end up being able to belong to multiple groups (similar to a tagging model) and groups can only belong to one other group (similar to a document structure).

Answer (score 4):

I hate to be a gem-pusher, but I recently started using [`ancestry`](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry), and it works very well. It has a unique way of indexing ancestors and descendants for great performance.

There's also a [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/262-trees-with-ancestry) that covers it.

> Ancestry is a gem/plugin that allows the records of a Ruby on Rails
>   ActiveRecord model to be organised as a tree structure (or hierarchy).
>   It uses a single, intuitively formatted database column, using a
>   variation on the materialised path pattern. It exposes all the
>   standard tree structure relations (ancestors, parent, root, children,
>   siblings, descendants) and all of them can be fetched in a single SQL
>   query. Additional features are STI support, scopes, depth caching,
>   depth constraints, easy migration from older plugins/gems, integrity
>   checking, integrity restoration, arrangement of (sub)tree into hashes
>   and different strategies for dealing with orphaned records.
>
> Source: https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry#readme